# Vagrant Artifactory OSS install url throws 404 error

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, artifactory

I'm using vagrant for managing ubuntu and have installed Jenkins and trying my hand at artifactory. This is installed but after running the install.sh script it shows that service is running but url (IP:port) throws a 404 error. Tried a search and couldn't find any workaround except for using the artifactory name during install.sh. Artifactory is installed under "var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/"

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/artifactory] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.57
```

Nothing in localhost logs under catalina but catalina.out log  has the below SEVERE exception.

```
16-Aug-2020 21:43:41.609 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml]
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.WarResourceSet@1b9c0f74]

Aug-2020 21:06:28.670 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml]
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/artifactory]]
```

I have tried both install.sh as is and specifying user group as args

```
install.sh artifactory artifactory
```

Versions:

```
ubuntu-xenial 16.04.7 LTS
jfrog-artifactory-oss-6.21.0.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error snippet it looks like access service is having issues coming up. Can you please check the access service log for the issue?
On the other hand, this issue also could happen due to an invalid access version being printed to /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/access/data/access.env.version file. Can you update the access version using the below command and see if it resolves the issue?

`echo "4" > /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/access/data/access.env.version`

Comment: Thanks @Lakshmi Prasad, I don't see any access logs. Only files under artifactory/ are 
`./tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml
./webapps/access.war
./misc/tomcat/access.xml` 

I can't even find access/ folder under artifactory/. Is that a problem? Should I try a different version of artifactory ?

Comment: can you check for access env version file location under these directories?
$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/data/access/
/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/access

Comment: I can't even find access/ folder or even var/ under artifactory/ :(. All I can find are :  ---

`vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory$ ls       
-Access-Third-Parties-Usage-About-Box.html  
-bin  
-COPYING.AFFERO  
-etc  
-etc.original  
-logs  
-misc  
-README.txt  
-Third-Parties-Usage-About-Box.html  
-tomcat      
-webapps  `

Comment: can you run a find command for the file access.env.version and see?

Comment: I tried that already. That's why it's baffling me. I only found 3 access* files -> `vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory$ sudo find . -type f -name "access*"
./tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml
./webapps/access.war
./misc/tomcat/access.xml`

Comment: if that is the case i doubt the access service came up or not. can you check for any access application errors in the logs. generally under $Artifactory_home/access/logs/access.log